# Mouse pointer after some html elements

Tags: javascript, mouse, mathjax, mouse-cursor

I created paragraph input element. I typed some text and then I added some html element(*mjx-container*) via MathJax external library. When I added some text **after** *mjx-container*, mouse pointer automatically moves before *mjx-container* and in result I cannot add any text after *mjx-container*.

How can I allow mouse pointer after any element added to input element?

I added some text via code after *mjx-container* and then I could type new text after *mjx-container*, but when I deleted text after *mjx-container*, again mouse pointers moves back before *mjx-container*

[image: I want have cursor after mjx-container]

[image]

Comment: You should include your code as text; images are not easily searchable, nor copy/pasteable, making it difficult to debug.